# Crazy terminal behavior

Tags: bash, terminal, shell, ffmpeg

I am trying to run a script to rip all the audio from a bunch of MP4 files. Everything works when I do it line by line cutting and pasting from my text editor into terminal, but when I create a shell script to do it, I get one set of errors, if I cut and paste multiple lines, I get a different error.

I can create a foreach loop to do this, but trying to understand what is going wrong. Here is part of the shell script:

```
#/bin/bash
ffmpeg -i  969_BIO03.1-Introduction-to-Molecular-Genetics.mp4 -b:a 192K -vn BIO03.1-Introduction-to-Molecular-Genetics.mp3
ffmpeg -i  970_BIO03.2-DNA-Replication.mp4 -b:a 192K -vn BIO03.2-DNA-Replication.mp3
ffmpeg -i  971_BIO03.3-DNA-Repair.mp4 -b:a 192K -vn BIO03.3-DNA-Repair.mp3
ffmpeg -i  972_BIO03.4-Transcription.mp4 -b:a 192K -vn BIO03.4-Transcription.mp3
```

Again, if I copy just one line, everything is fine. If I execute the script I get:

```
# ./ripaudio.sh 
ffmpeg version N-52501-gd783297 Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
  built on May 14 2013 15:57:34 with gcc 4.4.7 (GCC) 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-3)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264
  libavutil      52. 27.101 / 52. 27.101
  libavcodec     55.  6.100 / 55.  6.100
  libavformat    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
  libavdevice    55.  0.100 / 55.  0.100
  libavfilter     3. 60.102 /  3. 60.102
  libswscale      2.  2.100 /  2.  2.100
  libswresample   0. 17.102 /  0. 17.102
  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '969_BIO03.1-Introduction-to-Molecular-Genetics.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf55.3.100
  Duration: 00:08:30.49, start: 0.021333, bitrate: 733 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 720x480 [SAR 32:27 DAR 16:9], 596 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 11988 tbn, 59.94 tbc
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
'NULL @ 0x243c8c0] Unable to find a suitable output format for 'BIO03.1-Introduction-to-Molecular-Genetics.mp3
: Invalid argumenton-to-Molecular-Genetics.mp3
ffmpeg version N-52501-gd783297 Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
  built on May 14 2013 15:57:34 with gcc 4.4.7 (GCC) 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-3)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264
  libavutil      52. 27.101 / 52. 27.101
  libavcodec     55.  6.100 / 55.  6.100
  libavformat    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
  libavdevice    55.  0.100 / 55.  0.100
  libavfilter     3. 60.102 /  3. 60.102
  libswscale      2.  2.100 /  2.  2.100
  libswresample   0. 17.102 /  0. 17.102
  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '970_BIO03.2-DNA-Replication.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf55.3.100
  Duration: 00:27:38.52, start: 0.021333, bitrate: 709 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 720x480 [SAR 32:27 DAR 16:9], 572 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 11988 tbn, 59.94 tbc
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
'NULL @ 0x357b8a0] Unable to find a suitable output format for 'BIO03.2-DNA-Replication.mp3
: Invalid argumentation.mp3
```

If I then take a group of 3 or so and paste those in I get this:

```
ffmpeg -i  974_BIO05.2-Prokaryotes.mp4 -b:a 192K -vn BIO05.2-Prokaryotes.mp3
ffmpeg version N-52501-gd783297 Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
  built on May 14 2013 15:57:34 with gcc 4.4.7 (GCC) 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-3)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264
  libavutil      52. 27.101 / 52. 27.101
  libavcodec     55.  6.100 / 55.  6.100
  libavformat    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
  libavdevice    55.  0.100 / 55.  0.100
  libavfilter     3. 60.102 /  3. 60.102
  libswscale      2.  2.100 /  2.  2.100
  libswresample   0. 17.102 /  0. 17.102
  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '974_BIO05.2-Prokaryotes.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf55.3.100
  Duration: 00:21:53.75, start: 0.021333, bitrate: 708 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 720x480 [SAR 32:27 DAR 16:9], 571 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 11988 tbn, 59.94 tbc
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Output #0, mp3, to 'BIO05.2-Prokaryotes.mp3':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    TSSE            : Lavf55.3.100
    Stream #0:0(eng): Audio: mp3, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 192 kb/s
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:0 (aac -> libmp3lame)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
stream #1:390kB time=00:00:16.58 bitrate= 192.6kbits/s    
  keyframe=1
  duration=0.021
  dts=332.480  pts=332.480
  size=375
stream #1:
  keyframe=1
  duration=0.021
  dts=332.501  pts=332.501
  size=355

[trimmed out hundreds of lines of this repeating pattern]


stream #1:
  keyframe=1
  duration=0.021
  dts=337.109  pts=337.109
  size=364
stream #1:
  keyframe=1
  duration=0.021
  dts=337.131  pts=337.131
  size=318

Enter command: <target> <time> <command>[ <argument>]
Parse error, at least 3 arguments were expected, only 1 given in string 'ell.mp4 -b:a 192K -vn BIO06.1-Anatomy-of-the-Cell.mp3'
size=    8408kB time=00:05:58.70 bitrate= 192.0kbits/s    
Enter command: <target> <time> <command>[ <argument>]
```

I am just trying to understand what went wrong here, I have written a decent number of scripts over the years, and the one thing about Unix it it always is consistent. your script might be broken, but it is consistent about that till you get your command right.

I am using SecureCRT as a terminal client.

Comment: I am trying to understand the question. It is not clear which of the examples work, which don't, which are inputs, which are outputs.

Comment: The only example that works is when I copy a single command, run it, and copy the next line. If I try batching them, it fails. A similar script worked a couple weeks ago doing the same task, but today it doesn't.

Answer (score 3):

i had the same exact problem on my batch script written to just compress all my mp4 video contained in a folder and in it's sub folders, i turned out (after 3 days of googleing) that ffmpeg by default allow the transcoding in realtime of the streaming in charge, and so the possibility to interact with the settings of the stream, this mean that when commands are in a batch script, the first is executed correctly and the second string is interpreted as an interactive command, so it prints errors until some sort of buffer is full and the script crash, i saved my day by adding `-nostdin` to the ffmpeg command line, and now all work correctly.

Saluti, Massimiliano

Answer (score 2):

Based on the following line:

```
Parse error, at least 3 arguments were expected, only 1 given in string 'ell.mp4 -b:a 192K -vn BIO06.1-Anatomy-of-the-Cell.mp3'
```

It appears that the shell is thinking all of `ell.mp4 -b:a 192K -vn BIO06.1-Anatomy-of-the-Cell.mp3` is a single token, and it's not recognizing the spaces. I'm willing to bet those aren't space characters at all, but something else that renders like a space character.

Perform the following command and look carefully at the output

```
od -c name_of_your_script.sh | less
```

This will dump each printable character as the printable character, and all non-printable characters as their ASCII code (I think it's in octal). Anyway, look for this specific string I pasted into my answer, and look for the spaces between the arguments. If you see something other than a space there, that's your problem.

Comment: Some of the errors, like `: Invalid argumenton-to-Molecular-Genetics.mp3`, also look like [windows-line-endings problems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613800/how-to-convert-dos-windows-newline-to-unix-newline-in-bash-script) (carriage return & line feed at the end of each line, & the shell thinks the carriage return is part of the command). All of which boils down to one thing: your text editor is screwing up the file format.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing an ! at the first line of your script I think, it should be:

`#!/bin/bash`

By the way, another way to do this, if you have all the .mp4 files in the current directory, would be this in bash:

```
for file in `ls *.mp4 | cut -d '.' -f -1 `; 
do 
ffmpeg -i ${file}.mp4 -b:a 192k -vn ${file}.mp3; 
done
```

You can adjust the glob criteria in the *.mp4 to meet your needs (e.g. `ls ../media/bio123/97*BIO*.mp4`)

The breakdown of what is going on above:

```
ls *.mp4 // Get a list of all the MP4s in the current directory.
ls *.mp4 | cut -d '.' -f -1 // Get everything from the filename before the terminal . in the filename
```

Then the `${file}.mp4` syntax just helps the shell know I am talking about the `$file` variable defined in my for loop, not a variable called '`$file.mp4'`.  Finally there is nothing special about `file` - you could write the loop as:

```
for foo in `ls *.mp4 | cut -d '.' -f -1 `; 
do 
ffmpeg -i ${foo}.mp4 -b:a 192k -vn ${foo}.mp3; 
done
```